# jQuery stacking events

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox

So, i'm using FancyBox plugin to have a database entry editor. I have a "Save" and a Cancel Button, that when clicked, after they do what i want, trigger the close button so i can see the animation, with: `$('#fancybox-close').trigger('click');`

Now, i'm trying to do the oposite: when the user clicks fancybox's close button, i wan to run some code before what is defined for it to do, something like:

```
$('#fancybox-close').click(function(){
   //my code here
   //#fancybox-close event here
})
```

how can i do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [API page](http://fancybox.net/api) you can simply provide an `onClosed` handler when defining your FancyBox.

This function can then do whatever you'd like.

Comment: thanks, but this is just an example for me, i want to know how can i do this with jQuery

Comment: Generally speaking, if there weren't already a function defined to do what you want, write one. Then call it. If you're not concerned with how specifically your multiple event handlers chain together, just write multiple handlers for the same event. JavaScript will happily execute all of them.

Comment: but i want my events to have a specific order, the one i write must be executed before the one that is already written

Comment: Then write your first function so that its default behavior can be canceled and new behavior written instead (and the default function can still be called separately). The FancyBox API you cited is a great example of that. Override `onClosed` if you want, and then call `$.fancybox.close()` if you want.